# jqGrid - userData undefined

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm getting undefined for userData:

```
var userdata = $('#case_grid').getGridParam('userData');
    if (userdata) {
    alert(userdata.consultations);
```

with the following JSON output:

```
{"page":"1","total":"1","records":"1","userdata":{"consultations":"3"},"rows":[{"user_id":"00082563","name":"Peter Browne","case_title":"Male with STI (urethritis)","case_started":"2017-06-16 14:53:47","status":"Completed"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just changed the code a bit and got it working with this:

```
loadComplete: function () {
          var userdata = $('#case_grid').getGridParam('userData');
          if (userdata) {
          var consultations = userdata.consultations;
           }
              },
```